# encounter ConnectionClosingException when trying to put data into a hbase table

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, hadoop2

I tried to run spark job to operate on *hbase*, but it reported such a problem:

```
Failed to get region location 
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Call to hostname/ip:60020 failed on local exception: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Connection to hostname/ip:60020 is closing. Call id=139, waitTime=2
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.wrapException(AbstractRpcClient.java:288).
```

The machines in the same cluster prove to be able to connect one another. *kerberos* is used, but i configured the parameters needed and it didn't report any problem related to *kerberos* authentication or stuff like that. anyone can help with that? i appreciate very much. thank you.

Comment: Do you have `hbase-site.xml` in a directory that is in the driver Classpath? Otherwise the HBase client will silently revert to default values, and try to contact ZooKeeper on *localhost*... and you need ZK to locate the HBase Master, then the Master to get "region locations".

Comment: thanks. I added hbase-site.xml by --files and it doesn't display connectionclosingexception; However, it's starting to show  such an error as "No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)" , but i have correctly configure the kerberos keytab and krb5.conf file

Comment: I rechecked the configurations related to kerberos and didn't find out any abnormality.

Comment: And now i am still facing such issue: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.ConnectionClosingException: Connection to hostname/ip:60020 is closing. Call id=104, waitTime=17
 
Reading reply sessionid:0x358e84be173180b, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 417,8  replyHeader:: 417,150324029746,0  request:: '/hbase,F  response:: v{'meta-region-server,'acl,'backup-masters,'region-in-transition,'draining,'table,'running,'table-lock,'master,'tokenauth,'namespace,'hbaseid,'online-snapshot,'replication,'recovering-regions,'splitWAL,'rs,'flush-table-proc}

Comment: Some dirty tricks to activate the JAAS and Kerberos debug traces when using the Hadoop auth library (which HBase client uses): `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` and `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true`
 cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html

Comment: For the record, in case you use custom Java code and a JAAS conf file to access a kerberized service: `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`  and `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` for RPC or JDBC, the same plus `-Dsun.security.spnego.debug=true` for HTTP

Comment: i have resolved this issue by using spark on hbase.